# Create OBJECT with column values as Key in Snowflake

Tags: sql, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have multiple priority columns FROM Table A.

```
Priority_A    Priority_B      SOURCE      KEY
    1            1              A         Z
   NULL          NULL          NULL       Z
   NULL          2              B         Z
   NULL          NULL          NULL       Y
   NULL          NULL          NULL       Y
   NULL          3              C         Y
   NULL          3              C         Z
```

I want to create a single OBJECT in Snowflake using this column as its KEY.

When I do

```
SELECT OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(KEY, OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(PRIORITY_A, SOURCE
                                              PRIORITY_B, SOURCE)) AS Prio FROM A
```

I do not get a single object. I get 7 OBJECTS on 7 different rows. I want Snowflake to output one OBJECT with the following output.

```
{'Z':{
PRIORITY_B:{
      1:A
      2:B
      3:C
      
            }
PRIORITY_A:{
      1:A
            }
      }
'Y':{PRIORITY_B:{3:C}
     }
}
```

So we have one Object with some keys from colomn Key. This key has two OBJECTS as its value, with keys equal to the columnName, namely Priority_A and Priority_B.

Is this possible in Snowflake?

If not, I am also okay with the following output, with two different OBJECTS on two rows:

Object 1:

```
{'Z':{
PRIORITY_B:{
      1:A
      2:B
      3:C
            }
PRIORITY_A:{
      1:A
            }
      }
}
```

Object 2 on row 2:

```
{'Y':{PRIORITY_B:{3:C}}}
```

Comment: Hi - what you're describing is having "1:A 2:B 3:C" as a single string rather than as 3 key-value pairs. Can you confirm that this is actually what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Not really, I do mean 1 as the key and A as the value corresponding to that key. The colon is more for lay-out purposes. So I don't literally need "1:A" as a string. In the Snowflake IDE 1:A in the result viewer denotes 1 as the key and A as the value.

Comment: OK - but just to be clear then that what you are trying to construct is not valid JSON (or valid in any other format I'm aware of), it's just a structure that you've come up with. This is not an issue in itself but does mean you can't use functions like OBJECT_CONSTRUCT - which produce JSON structures, valid arrays, etc.

Comment: I might have made a mistake in my notation. Other than that, those are valid JSON objects in Snowflake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use group by to group on Key, and then aggregate. Try this:

```
SELECT 
   object_construct(KEY, OBJECT_AGG(priority,source::variant))
FROM 
    A 
where priority is not null and source is not null
GROUP BY 
    KEY;
```

updated solution for the updated question:

```
WITH PriorityB AS (
    SELECT 
        KEY, 
        OBJECT_AGG(PRIORITY_B, SOURCE::variant) as PRIORITY_B_JSON
    FROM A
    WHERE PRIORITY_B IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY KEY
),
PriorityA AS (
    SELECT 
        KEY, 
        OBJECT_AGG(PRIORITY_A, SOURCE::variant) as PRIORITY_A_JSON
    FROM A
    WHERE PRIORITY_A IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY KEY
)
SELECT 
    COALESCE(a.KEY, b.KEY) as KEY,
    OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(
        'PRIORITY_B', b.PRIORITY_B_JSON, 
        'PRIORITY_A', a.PRIORITY_A_JSON
    ) AS result
FROM PriorityA a
FULL OUTER JOIN PriorityB b ON a.KEY = b.KEY;
```

Comment: And what if you have multiple priority columns? OBJECT_AGG only seems to work with one column

Comment: @Eren I updated my answer, I could solve it with CTE, doing OBJECT_AGG for each column. then combining results. Hope it helps.